# Angel List API get startups from location

Tags: php, api, integration

I'm using Angel List API in my project and I want to get startups from the United States location but I didn't find any url for this in API documentation.
I also want to paginate the results.

I have currently used this url for market tag id = 25

```
$data_url = "https://api.angel.co/1/tags/25/startups?access_token=";

$startups = file_get_contents( $data_url.$access_token );
```

Answer (score 1):

To search by location, ie San Fransisco,

```
{
  "id": 1692,
  "tag_type": "LocationTag",
  "name": "san francisco",
  "display_name": "San Francisco",
  "angellist_url": "http://angel.co/san-francisco"
},
```

You can request the API with its id like this:

```
$data_url = "https://api.angel.co/1/tags/1692/startups?access_token=";
$startups = file_get_contents( $data_url.$access_token );
```

To find the US locationTag, you can [search](https://angel.co/api/spec/search) it by its slug and by precising the type of tag you want:

```
$data_url = "https://api.angel.co/1/search/slug?query=united-states&type=LocationTag&access_token=";
$unitedStatesLocationTag = file_get_contents( $data_url.$access_token );
```

And for pagination, it's explained [here](https://angel.co/api):

> **Pagination**
>
> Responses that return collections of objects are by default paginated
>   to 50 objects per page. If the endpoint returns ids, the default is
>   1000 ids per page. If the endpoint returns activity feed items, the
>   default is 25 items per page. **You may supply the page and per_page
>   parameters to control pagination**. However, you can never request more
>   than the default.
>
> Paginated requests will include metadata in the root of the response
>   object similar to the following:
>
> ```
>  {
>    "users": [ ... ],
>    "total": 13723,
>    "per_page": 50,
>    "page": 1,
>    "last_page": 275,
>  }
> ```

Comment: Hi thanks for your help. I have tried that second url but i am getting
"failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request error " :(

Comment: is it because of &access_token ?? and i need startups list is it need to define startups in url?

Comment: I don't know. If you don't include 'startups' in your url, the API won't know what you want to retrieve.

Comment: Hi can u tell me that united-states is match with country or city??

Comment: When you search by location on their site for North America (https://angel.co/north-america), it lists 'united-states' as children (https://angel.co/united-states) so it matches with country. You can refine more by state with the corresponding slug if you need.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103735/discussion-between-rk1212-and-veve).